# AttributeError: Tensor.name is undefined when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

Code:

```
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr, 0.9)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[labels, outputs], tape=tape)
        del tape
```

Getting the Error:
`AttributeError: Tensor.name is undefined when eager execution is enabled.`

How to resolve it?